# Determine if a path is local Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to play an audio by using package [audioplayer](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayer) but I cannot always know if a path is a local file or not. Therefore, I wonder what is the best way to determine if a path is local in Flutter?

Answer (score 0):

Both `File` and `Directory` classes of `dart:io` library has `isAbsolute` method, which checks if a File or Directory path is absolute or not.

```dart
final file = File('foo/bar');
print(file.isAbsolute);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/// check if a path is local path in OS filesystem JUST in syntax not really
// final bool isAbsolutePath = !_imagePath!.contains('http://');
// final bool isAbsolutePath = File(_imagePath!).isAbsolute; // import 'dart:io';
final bool isAbsolutePath = p.isAbsolute(_imagePath!); // import 'package:path/path.dart' as p;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).